# Neo4j values from WITH disappears if subsequent MATCH fails

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I ran into this issue I have a cypher that passes on data using `WITH`

```
MATCH (u1:user {username: "pewpewlasers"}), (u2:user {username: "pewpew2"})
MERGE (u1)-[y:KNOWS]->(u2)
ON CREATE SET y.connected = 1
WITH y, has(y.connected) AS connected 
REMOVE y.connected
RETURN connected
```

This works. When `KNOWS` relationship is created, `connected` is `true` else `false`. And so either `true` or `false` is returned by this cypher. Now I want to extend this

```
MATCH (u1:user {username: "pewpewlasers"}), (u2:user {username: "pewpew2"})
MERGE (u1)-[y:KNOWS]->(u2)
ON CREATE SET y.connected = 1
WITH y, has(y.connected) AS connected 
REMOVE y.connected
WITH y, connected
MATCH (x)-[zz:LIKES]->(y)    <------------- this match
WITH zz, connected
RETURN zz, connected
```

NOW `connected` returns `true` or `false` only if the marked match succeeds. Otherwise it gives an empty result. I want `connected` to return `true` or `false` regardless of whether `MATCH` succeeds or not.

**EDIT:**

**Sorry I left out something in the second query.**

```
MATCH (u1:user {username: "pewpewlasers"}), (u2:user {username: "pewpew2"})
MERGE (u1)-[y:KNOWS]->(u2)
ON CREATE SET y.connected = 1
WITH y, has(y.connected) AS connected 
REMOVE y.connected
WITH y, connected
MATCH (x)-[zz:LIKES]->(y)    <------------- this match
MERGE x-[:LOVES]->(y)        <------------- EDIT
WITH zz, connected
RETURN zz, connected
```

Optional match while solves the match issue, it will fail with merge giving `null` error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this may do the trick.

```
MATCH (u1:user {username: "pewpewlasers"}), (u2:user {username: "pewpew2"})
MERGE (u1)-[y:KNOWS]->(u2)
ON CREATE SET y.connected = 1
WITH y, has(y.connected) AS connected 
REMOVE y.connected
WITH y, connected
OPTIONAL MATCH (x)-[zz:LIKES]->(yy)
FOREACH(ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN yy IS null THEN [] ELSE [1] END |
    MERGE x-[:LOVES]->(yy))
WITH zz, connected
RETURN zz, connected
```

OPTIONAL MATCH allows you to keep all your initial rows and then you'll have a null value for 'zz' if there is no relationship.

Comment: Your solution makes sense. However, I had missed out on a detail. Please have a look at the edit if you have some time. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this gives me this error **Error: Type mismatch: y already defined with conflicting type Relationship (expected Node)**

Comment: Ah yeh because y is defined earlier on. We can call the second one 'yy' in that case.